# How to exclude subdomains from redirecting?

Tags: regex, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code to force any URL to be "https://www.":

```
#rewrite to WWW:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(\d+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(\d+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have sub-domains and I do not want any of them to be redirected. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you think this is duplicate , but there was not any question that contains both www and https redirections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:static\.|subdomain1\.|subdomain2\.|\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: I have used this code but it will redirect static.domain.com to https ://www .static.domain.com

Comment: I tried but i faced internal server error , i think it caused a loop

Comment: Just fixed it, that was an extra `)`. Try it now